# Right Split Exact Sequence implies Semi-Direct Product - Why?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A remark from Wikipedia,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma

(about an exact sequence) $0\to A\to B\to C\to 1$

says " if a short exact sequence of groups is right split ... then it need not be left split or a direct sum ...  what is true in this case is that B is a semidirect product, though not in general a direct product."

I cannot verify this, in particular showing that $AC = B$ is giving me problems as I don't know how to work with the right inverse (injection?) map $u:C\to B$.

If I define the map $\psi:AC\to B$ by $(a,c)\mapsto au(c)$, I want to show it is a bijection.  But I can't even show it is well-defined.  Is this the right bijection?

Comment: Actually I think I figured this out.  The AC = B axiom anyway.

Comment: I was wrong, I was able to show the map is well-defined though using the fact that $f:B\to C$ satisties $f\circ u = id_{C}$.  I wasn't able to show that the map is injective or surjective though.

Comment: OK! I got surjectivity.  I had to use the isomorphism between $C$ and $B/A$.

Comment: Dear lovinglife, Given that you have the map $u$, the map $(a,c) \mapsto a u(c)$ is certainly well-defined (although it may not be immediately obvious that it has all the other properties you need).  What makes you concerned that it is not well-defined? Regards,

Comment: Sorry I was confusing maps.  For the map I said above, injectivity is what I was really seeking.  Actually this confusion was what was holding me back.  Surjectivity was the valuable exercise though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the maps $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $g:B \rightarrow C$.  We have $B/f(A) \cong C$ with isomorphism induced by $g$ whose inverse is given by composition of $u$ with natural projection.  Let $b \in B$.  Then $u(g(b))*f(A) = b*f(A)$ so $u(g(b))=b*f(a)$ for some $a \in A$.  Then $f(a^{-1})*u(g(b)) = b$.  This proves $B = f(A)*u(C)$.  That $f(A)$ is normal in $B$  and that $f(A) \cap u(C) = 1$ follows easily from being a short exact sequence.